# How to enforce __weak reference in parameters for protocol implementation

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a protocol for which I want the implementations to use __weak references for method arguments. I define my protocol as:

```
@protocol TestProtocol
-(void) op:(__weak NSObject*)x;
@end
```

Then I create an implementation:

```
-(void) op:(NSObject*)x
{
}
```

And x becomes an strong reference. If I move the __weak declaration to the protocol implementation, 'x' is a weak reference.

As the caller of the protocol already keeps a strong reference, I want to ensure that the implementations don't create another strong reference.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The caller doesn't need to care about that the method does with variables. The implementation of the method may, but should declare that itself.

Comment: The thing is that if X is retained and op throws, x is leaked, but if X is a weak reference it doesn't leak. As in my case the the caller always keeps a strong reference there isn't need for op to do it, and i avoid leaks with exceptions.

Comment: But why are you throwing x?

Comment: not throwing x, but the implementation of op could throw, in this case ARC doesn't release x see http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#exceptions

Comment: "The standard Cocoa convention is that exceptions signal programmer error and are not intended to be recovered from." So the app should crash and the leak is cleaned when the app is killed.

Comment: @hypercrypt Please stop trying to teach him that exceptions are bad. He never said _he's_ throwing them, if an Apple method does that it'd be good to at least not leak if the exception is handled. Anyway, it's a detail that has nothing to do with the main question: _Why is the __weak attribute lost?_ which is a very valid question, IMHO.

Comment: The documentation presents a flag if you need this functionality; otherwise, if you're following Apple's guidelines, drive on. Don't make your code so darn complicated.

Comment: @DarkDust There is no point in ensuring that leaks don't occur during exception handling exactly because exceptions are intended to be fatal;  they are not recoverable.   So, yes, "Don't bother" is a valid answer to a "I'm trying to fix a leak caused by @throw".  Still, the original question is interesting in and of itself, agreed.

Comment: According to 3.2 of that document: In general, ARC does not perform retain or release operations when simply using a retainable object pointer as an operand within an expression. This includes:
1) loading a retainable pointer from an object with non-weak ownership,
2) passing a retainable pointer as an argument to a function or method, and
3) receiving a retainable pointer as the result of a function or method call. http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#retainable-object-pointers-as-operands-and-arguments

Comment: @dans3itz I couldn't find said flag. What is it?

Comment: -fobjc-arc-exceptions This works fine to prevent the leaks with ARC in presence of exceptions. And is also the default for Objetive-C++

Comment: @José Ah -- I was thinking of a flag to warn on mismatched declaration, not that one.   Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a tad surprised the compiler doesn't complain about a declaration mismatch.  And, sure enough, it doesn't.  I filed radar #13730581 to see what the compiler folks say.

As @hypercrypt cites, ARC isn't going to retain or release the arguments to a method in the general case.   One of the few cases where the performance vs. correctness sacrifice was large enough to warrant such a tradeoff.   (Note that you'll see a storeStrong in the non-optimized case but no such thing in the -Os case Release build case).

Which means you are really defending against a strong reference being created against the object by implication of the code in the method body (and, as per comments, that said strong reference isn't torn down when an `@throw` goes "over" the frame).

There isn't much you can do about that -- if you pass `x` off to, say, `NSMutableArray`'s `addObject:` method, it'll create a strong reference.

Thus, in the general case, there isn't really a means of preventing a strong reference to an object from being created as a side effect of variable usage.

Specific to NSException cleanup, it isn't worth worrying about.  Exceptions should be fatal and the state of the app after an exception is thrown is undefined (unless you can ensure that no system code was in any way involved with the exception, which isn't really viable).

```
// code tossed in main.m to play w/compiler behavior

@protocol TestProtocol
-(void) op:(__weak NSObject*)x;
@end

@interface DogBowl:NSObject <TestProtocol>
@end
@implementation DogBowl
-(void) op:(NSObject*)x
{
}
@end
```